# Arabic text showing as special charaters

Tags: android, android-studio, utf-8, special-characters, arabic

I am using arabic text on server and when I fetch it looks like this
is this server encoding issue or I have to handle it on mobile side? 
When I add arabic text from website and into db it comes perfect in app but not when I submit from `edittext` in android
need help and suggestions.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Lokk for retriving from server and sending to server in UTF-8 format.